# Uncaught TypeError: l(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

Any idea what's wrong with the following function? I tried placing the jQuery before the function but it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
! function(l) {
    l(window).load(function() {
        l(".scrolling").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "mini-dark",
            scrollButtons: {
                enable: !0
            },
            callbacks: {
                onTotalScroll: function() {
                    addContent(this)
                },
                onTotalScrollOffset: 100,
                alwaysTriggerOffsets: !1
            }
        })
    })
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Most probably, you haven't placed "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js" script before the above code.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. But if I had to guess, it is either `.scrolling` element doesn't exist at the time of execution, or that `mCustomScrollbar` widget is not properly installed and thus not visible as a factory method.

Comment: @sudip thanks, but now I get 'jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at k.fn.init.k.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
    at (index):607
    at (index):607'

Comment: @JacobK.Not enough information. Use jsfiddle or similar online JS editor and share it here.